# How to use the irb while taking into account a method that I wrote on Nitrous.IO?

Tags: irb, nitrousio

I have a file with a class on a file in `Nitrous.io`.

I want to start the irb or rails console and make new objects and manipulate them etc. How do I open the console with that specific file taken into account?

Answer (score 0):

Use rails console by typing:

```
rails c
```

or

```
rails console
```